# knife-vsphere plugin not working

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Following adding 'knife-vsphere' to my cookbook's Gemfile:

```
gem 'knife-vsphere'
```

I try to use the following command:

```
knife vsphere vm list
```

And i get the following error:
"FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'vsphere'"

Clearly knife isn't even aware that it's installed, but it is.

OS X 10.10.3
Chef 12.3.0 (in /opt/chefdk/bin)
Ruby 2.2.2 via Rbenv

knife-vsphere: https://github.com/ezrapagel/knife-vsphere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
chef gem install knife-vsphere
```

to install it into ChefDK's ruby ([docs](http://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef.html#chef-gem)).

Comment: It's amazing I couldn't find this anywhere. Now someone else can. :) Thank you.

Comment: I had a follow-on, but un-related problem, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561953/why-am-i-getting-prompted-for-sudo-password-via-knife-vsphere-when-giving-ssh